# Saving Sequelize Record/Referencing it in Another Model

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a postrgresql/Sequelize model called `Segment`, which belongs to many models:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Segment = sequelize.define(
    'segment',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      provider_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'provider',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      summary_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'summary',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      audience_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'audience',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      onboarding_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'onboarding',
          key: 'id'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      // disable the modification of table names; By default, sequelize will automatically
      // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
      // if you don't want that, set the following
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'segment'
    }
  );
  Segment.associate = models => {
    Segment.belongsTo(models.Provider, { foreignKey: 'id' });
    Segment.belongsTo(models.Summary, { foreignKey: 'id' });
    Segment.belongsTo(models.Audience, { foreignKey: 'id' });
    Segment.belongsTo(models.Onboarding, { foreignKey: 'id' });
  };
  return Segment;
};
```

The models that segment has associations to (ie `provider_id`, `summary_id`, `audience_id`, `onboarding_id`) look like this:

Provider:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Provider = sequelize.define(
    'provider',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      providerName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      privacyPolicy: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      }
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'provider'
    }
  );

  Provider.associate = models => {
    Provider.hasMany(models.Segment, { foreignKey: 'provider_id' });
  };

  return Provider;
};
```

Summary:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Summary = sequelize.define(
    'summary',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      summaryName: DataTypes.STRING,
      standardIdName: DataTypes.STRING,
      description: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'summary'
    }
  );

  Summary.associate = models => {
    Summary.hasMany(models.Segment, { foreignKey: 'summary_id' });
  };

  return Summary;
};
```

Audience:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Audience = sequelize.define(
    'audience',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      refreshCadence: DataTypes.STRING,
      sourceLookbackWindow: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'audience'
    }
  );

  Audience.associate = models => {
    Audience.hasMany(models.Segment, { foreignKey: 'audience_id' });
  };

  return Audience;
};
```

Onboarding:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Onboarding = sequelize.define(
    'onboarding',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      onboardingExpansions: DataTypes.STRING,
      onboardingAudiencePrecision: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'onboarding'
    }
  );

  Onboarding.associate = models => {
    Onboarding.hasMany(models.Segment, { foreignKey: 'onboarding_id' });
  };

  return Onboarding;
};
```

My question is: what should come first when creating and saving a Segment record? Do I create and save each one of the other models first (provider, summary, audience, onboarding), and then create/save a Segment with references to those ids? I don't really know what the order of events should be in this situation. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- TLDR:

In order to create an instance of `Segment`, you must have all 4 foreign keys reference exist records on the referenced tables(`provider`, `summary`, `audience` and `onboarding`).

- Explanation:

`provider`, `summary`, `audience` and `onboarding` tables are independent.

However, `Segment` model is **not** independent.
`Segment` model has 4 columns which are foreign keys.

[From PostgresSql Tutorial:](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/)

> A foreign key is a field or group of fields in a table that uniquely
>   identifies a row in another table. In other words, a foreign key is
>   defined in a table that references to the primary key of the other
>   table.
>
> The table that contains the foreign key is called referencing table or
>   child table. And the table to which the foreign key references is
>   called referenced table or parent table.

It means that a foreign key is a constraint that the column should reference the primary key of the referenced table.

So, you must create all the resources of a created row of `Segment`.